# Ignore folders but not recursively on Git

Tags: git

I have a tree structure looking like this, which I want to commit on Git.

```
├── A/
│   ├── lots of files
├── B/
│   ├── lots of files
├── samples
    ├── A/
    │   ├── not so much files
    ├── B/
    │   ├── not so much files
```

The following `.gitignore` ignores `A/` and `B/` recursively, but I would like to ignore only root level `A/` and `B/` folders to provide the user `samples/A/` and `samples/B/`

```
# .gitignore
A/
B/
```

What is the correct syntax for the `.gitignore` file? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a leading slash so the folders are ignored only on the root level.

```
# .gitignore
/A/
/B/
```